# session_set_cookie_params security and SSL

Tags: php, security, session, ssl

I'm trying to understand how secure session work over non secure connection using session set cookie params. Here's my code which is included in every page

```
session_set_cookie_params('43200','/','.mydomin.com',TRUE,TRUE);
session_start();
```

From php.net I quote "secure: If TRUE cookie will only be sent over secure connections. " but this page is not secured it's not using SSL it's only HTTP and I can sign in and create the session normally. I'm just trying to make the web page more secure through installing SSL.So how possible it is to create secure session over non secure connection?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: Did you read the description? `The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called.`

Comment: this function is in every page before session_start()

Comment: My question is how could the session be started without a secure connection though the SECURE flag is set to true

Comment: The secure flag will only be set if the connection is encrypted (ssl). A secure cookie can't be set (secure flag won't be set) if you're connected over HTTP and not HTTPS.

Comment: But the fact is the session has been started and I could log in without any problem while connecting through HTTP not HTTPS while secure is set to TRUE that's why I'm asking

Comment: The secure flag will only bet set if you connect over HTTPS from the beginning. And then the cookie will only be sent to the server when you connect over HTTPS.

Comment: Thank a lot @Charlotte Dunois now i understand you can add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.